# Calculate average weighted euclidean distance between values in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I searched a bit around and found comparable questions/answers, but none of them returned the correct results for me.

**Situation:**
I have an array with a number of clumps of values == 1, while the rest of the cells are set to zero. Each cell is a square (width=height).
Now I want to calculate the average distance between all 1 values.
The formula should be like this: `d = sqrt ( (( x2 - x1 )*size)**2 + (( y2 - y1 )*size)**2 )`

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

a = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1]])

# Given that each cell is 10m wide/high
val = 10
d = pdist(a, lambda u, v: np.sqrt( ( ((u-v)*val)**2).sum() ) )
d
array([ 14.14213562,  10.        ,  10.        ])
```

After that I would calculate the average via `d.mean()`. However the result in d is obviously wrong as the distance between the cells in the top-row should be 20 already (two crossed cells * 10). Is there something wrong with my formula, math or approach?

Answer (score 4):

You need the actual coordinates of the non-zero markers, to compute the distance between them:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist
>>> a = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
...               [0, 0, 0],
...               [0, 0, 1]])
>>> np.where(a)
(array([0, 0, 2]), array([0, 2, 2]))
>>> x,y = np.where(a)
>>> coords = np.vstack((x,y)).T
>>> coords
array([[0, 0],   # That's the coordinate of the "1" in the top left,
       [0, 2],   # top right,
       [2, 2]])  # and bottom right.
```

Next you want to calculate the distance between these points. You use `pdist` for this, like so:

```
>>> dists = pdist(coords) * 10  # Uses the Euclidean distance metric by default.
>>> squareform(dists)
array([[  0.        ,  20.        ,  28.28427125],
       [ 20.        ,   0.        ,  20.        ],
       [ 28.28427125,  20.        ,   0.        ]])
```

In this last matrix, you will find (above the diagonal), the distance between each marked point in `a` and another coordinate. In this case, you had 3 coordinates, so it gives you the distance between node 0 (`a[0,0]`) and node 1 (`a[0,2]`), node 0 and node 2 (`a[2,2]`) and finally between node 1 and node 2. To put it in different words, if `S = squareform(dists)`, then `S[i,j]` returns the distance between the coordinates on row `i` of `coords` and row `j`.

Just the values in the upper triangle of that last matrix are also present in the variable `dist`, from which you can derive the mean easily, without having to perform the relatively expensive calculation of the `squareform` (shown here just for demonstration purposes):

```
>>> dists
array([ 20.        ,  28.2842712,  20.        ])
>>> dists.mean()
22.761423749153966
```

Remark that your computed solution "looks" nearly correct (aside from a factor of 2), because of the example you chose. What `pdist` does, is it takes the Euclidean distance between the first point in the n-dimensional space and the second and then between the first and the third and so on. In your example, that means, it computes the distance between a point on row 0: that point has coordinates in 3 dimensional space given by `[1,0,1]`. The 2nd point is `[0,0,0]`. The Euclidean distance between those two `sqrt(2)~1.4`. Then, the distance between the first and the 3rd coordinate (the last row in `a`), is only `1`. Finally, the distance between the 2nd coordinate (row 1: `[0,0,0]`) and the 3rd (last row, row 2: `[0,0,1]`) is also `1`. So remember, `pdist` interprets its first argument as a stack of coordinates in n-dimensional space, `n` being the number of elements in the tuple of each node.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. I did not use the `np.where` and `np.vstack`commands up so far, so I will try that out. Sadly it still returns wrong values for my example dataset (which is a lot larger and the clumps of *1* are much bugger and irregular shaped). My guess is that something with the formula is not right yet, but I will investigate

Comment: @Curlew, the way you've described the problem, you made it seem like each "clump" was a single marker, a single element (1) surrounded by zeros. If however you have an actual "clump", for example a connected region of 1's, that e.g. represents the location of a particle in real life, then you should take the center of that clump. But that changes your question, so you might want to consider asking a new question then and providing more details about the actual dataset (is it perhaps a binary photo of organisms?).